# how to Web Scraping a dynamic page in android with JSOUP

Tags: java, android, kotlin, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to web scrape the website [savevideo.tube](https://savevideo.tube/31/) using JSOUP.

When we put a link in the search bar and click the search button, the website dynamically loads and shows some download links that I want to scrape. My problem is how to load link in JSOUP with the link search without clicking the search button and showing the results (scraping the results).

Is there any way to search for a link and load it without clicking any button and get results?

I tried this code but I'm not getting the required result.

```
  val result:Document = Jsoup.connect(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .data("url", Constants.YOUTUBE_LINK)
            .data("sid", "9823478982349872384789273489238904790234")
            .userAgent("Mozilla").post()
```

Answer (score 0):

JSOUP is a **Static HTML** parser. You cannot parse the content that is loaded by javascript dynamically. For that, you have to use a web drive.

The best web drives that you can use are

- [HTML Unit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/gettingStarted.html)
- [JBrowserDriver](https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver)

You can also use selenium but it may not be ideal for ***android***
:-

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ʀᴀʜɪʟ, JSOUP is a static HTML parser only. If you want to scrape a website that uses JS generated content you should probably take a look at [skrape.it](https://github.com/skrapeit/skrape.it#scrape-a-client-side-rendered-page) library

```kotlin
fun getDocumentByUrl(urlToScrape: String) = skrape(BrowserFetcher) { // <--- pass BrowserFetcher to include rendered JS
    request { url = urlToScrape }
    response { htmlDocument { this } }
}


fun main() {
    // do stuff with the document
}
```